# how to fix EXCEPTION ACCESS VIOLATION (Fatal Error has been detected by JVM)?

Tags: java, multithreading, apache, tomcat, jvm

Anyone knows what the cause of this error?

```
A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION[thread 13080 also had an error] (0xc0000005)    
[thread 13080 also had an error at pc=0x000000006dbba635
, pid=11944[thread 18684 also had an error], tid=16560
[thread 5180 also had an error]

JRE version: 6.0_18-b07
[thread 10208 also had an error]# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (16.0-b13 mixed mode windows-amd64 )

Problematic frame:
[thread 148 also had an error]
[thread 12524 also had an error]V
[jvm.dll+0x3ca635]

[thread 30620 also had an error]
[thread 10308 also had an error]
An error report file with more information is saved as:
[thread 10308 also had an error]
[thread 21492 also had an error]
[thread 4984 also had an error]

If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
```

If the information that I provide is not clear enough please comment or ask me.
I need the solution for this problem

Comment: A localhost URL is only going to work on your computer.  You need a LAN address if you're working within one LAN, or a public web address if you're working with the public.

Comment: provide more information. do you use native libraries? try different JDK.